# Advantages of Dynamixel X -T / -R TTL vs RS-485

Tags: dynamixel, ros-melodic, ros-lunar, ros-kinetic, ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm planning to buy servos for a humanoid robot that I control with ROS, is there any disadvantage of the TTL vs RS-485 versions? EMC/Electric disturbance / how many servos on one line/bus are possible... or others?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314885/advantages-of-dynamixel-x--t-/--r-ttl-vs-rs-485/) by [Johannes Jaegers](https://answers.ros.org/users/10981/johannes-jaegers/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2019-02-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you for your inquiry about Dynamixels.

Simply, the advantage of using RS-485 is more robustness when you need to long long communication line. If you have a plan to make humanoid robot, you could use TTL rather than RS-485.
And you can use Dynamixels up to 200 connected with additional power.

I think below link might good example for you.
http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/op3/introduction/

---

Originally posted by [Darby Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30440/darby-lim/) with karma: 811 on 2019-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Johannes Jaegers](https://answers.ros.org/users/10981/johannes-jaegers/) on 2019-02-08**:
Thank you very much!